# got wrong shape while using tf.train.batch

Tags: python, tensorflow

The shape of my data is (1920,60,2).
Assume the batch size is 128, expected the batch data shape will be (128,60,2).
but while using `tf.train.batch`, I got (128,1920,60,2),
does that mean I have to reshape the data first?

```
tf_X_train = tf.constant(X_train) # type(X_train):numpy.cdarray
tf_Y_train = tf.constant(Y_train)
tf_batch_xs, tf_batch_ys = tf.train.batch([tf_X_train, tf_Y_train], batch_size = 128, capacity = 5000)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    batch_xs, batch_ys = sess.run([tf_batch_xs, tf_batch_ys])

    print (batch_xs.shape )
```

got (128,1920,60,2) as output.

Another question, `tf.train.batch` should input tensor, but why does it still work while I input numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ar per the string documentation for the default-to-`False` `enqueue_many` argument of the `tf.train.batch` method:

> If `enqueue_many` is `False`, `tensors` is assumed to represent a single
>     example.  An input tensor with shape `[x, y, z]` will be output as a tensor
>     with shape `[batch_size, x, y, z]`.
>
> If `enqueue_many` is `True`, `tensors` is assumed to represent a batch of
>     examples, where the first dimension is indexed by example, and all members of
>     `tensors` should have the same size in the first dimension.  If an input
>     tensor has shape `[*, x, y, z]`, the output will have shape `[batch_size, x,
>     y, z]`.  The `capacity` argument controls the how long the prefetching is
>     allowed to grow the queues.

So to answer your question, you'll have to set the `enqueue_many` argument to `True` and the first dimension will be discarded or if you let `enqueue_many` to `False` you'll have to iterate over the first dimension of your array.

To answer your second question, `tensors` input goes internally through the `convert_to_tensor` method and therefore `numpy` array will be converted into TensorFlow `tensor`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm quite confused about how should I reshape my data?

Comment: You could for example iterate over the first dimension of your data and feed `tensors` of dimension '(60,2)'. Or you can set `enqueue_many` to `True`.

Comment: But I would advise you to have a look to the dataset api which should help you preprocessing your data. See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets